# Problem mounting internal floppy drive

Tags: 12.10, mount, floppy

This is the error I received when I tried mounting internal floppy drive:

```
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/fd0: Command-line `mount "/media/floppy0"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: /dev/fd0 is not a valid block device
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 0):

Command `mount /dev/fd0` was broken since lucid (i.e. Ubuntu 10.04).

Try using `udisks --mount /dev/fd0` instead (or `udisks --mount /media/floppy0` if you prefer).